# Making the ordering of a MySQL Query Depending on the Age of a Timestamp Field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For the query below, I am ordering it by `ORDER BY s.points DESC`, which is working fine.  But I would like to change it so that it orders by `s.points` descending only while `s.datesubmitted` is within the last hour.  The field `s.datesubmitted` is a timestamp.  Otherwise, I would like to order by `most_recent` descending.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
 $sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, s.points, s.datesubmitted, l.username,
           s.submissionid, s.subcheck, s.topten, COUNT(c.commentid) countComments, 
           GREATEST(s.datesubmitted, COALESCE(MAX(c.datecommented), s.datesubmitted)) AS most_recent
      FROM submission s
      JOIN login l ON s.loginid = l.loginid
 LEFT JOIN comment c ON s.submissionid = c.submissionid
  GROUP BY s.submissionid
  ORDER BY s.points DESC 

     LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use date functions such as sub/add etc. (mysql function)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, s.points, s.datesubmitted, l.username,
           s.submissionid, s.subcheck, s.topten, COUNT(c.commentid) countComments, 
           GREATEST(s.datesubmitted, COALESCE(MAX(c.datecommented), s.datesubmitted)) AS most_recent
      FROM submission s
      JOIN login l ON s.loginid = l.loginid
 LEFT JOIN comment c ON s.submissionid = c.submissionid
  GROUP BY s.submissionid

  ORDER BY s.points DESC, s.datesubmitted DESC
     WHERE s.datesubmitted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

     LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

I have nowhere to test it though.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL permits expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
...
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN s.submitted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
  THEN s.points ELSE GREATEST(s.datesubmitted, 
                        COALESCE(MAX(c.datecommented), s.datesubmitted)) END) DESC;
```

If, as I suspect, you actually want the last hour's first, and then the stale ones under the different ordering, add another ORDER BY variable before this one,

```
(CASE WHEN s.submitted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

and sort `DESC` on that too.

Comment: Could you show the full code for what you mean in the second half of your answer?

Comment: `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN s.submitted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, (CASE WHEN s.submitted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
  THEN s.points ELSE GREATEST(s.datesubmitted, 
                        COALESCE(MAX(c.datecommented), s.datesubmitted)) END) DESC`

Comment: Thanks... but that doesn't return any results.  Just a blank page.

Comment: That's with the same `SELECT` and everything at the beginning of the query. I didn't repeat that. You have `SELECT * FROM (bunch of tables with JOINS and conditions)` before the ORDER BY. ORDER BY can't reduce the number of rows returned.

Comment: What does it return with no `ORDER BY`?